# BlueZ gatttool notifications

Tags: bluetooth

I am working over the BlueZ Library gatttool but when I run the gatttool  command as mentioned below, it starts giving me notification endlessly. Is there is any way, that it gives the notification once and then exit the command?

Command:

```
gatttool -b BC:6A:29:AC:02:57 –char-write-req -a 0x2E -n 0100 –listen;
```

Output is:

```
Characteristic value/descriptor: 00
Characteristic value/descriptor: 01
Characteristic value was written successfully
Notification handle = 0x002d value: 01 06 40
Notification handle = 0x002d value: 01 05 40
Notification handle = 0x002d value: 01 06 40
Notification handle = 0x002d value: 01 06 44
Notification handle = 0x002d value: 01 05 41
Notification handle = 0x002d value: 01 06 41
....endless notifications..... I just need once
```

Answer (score 0):

just run it without `--listen` option.

```
gatttool -b BC:6A:29:AC:02:57 –char-write-req -a 0x2E -n 0100
```

Comment: That results in no notification at all. The question seems to be about waiting till the first one.